# SpecFlow Gherkin

Tags: specflow, gherkin

I am trying to run the *.feature file multiple times for different frame rates of the system.

This frame rate setting is a one time task that need to be made at the begging of the test execution. And this need to be in background. Later scenarios will be executed for different configuration.

Below is the code I written for background.

Background:

```
Given I have loaded the system configuration
And I change framerate to <framerate>
And I do "Online" download to system
And the system should be equal
```

Entire feature file need to be executed with different framerates.

Now I would like to pass this framerate as a argument at the BACKGROUND.

Could you please let me know how "framerate" can be passed as argument of different values in background?

Comment: Background:
Given I have loaded the system configuration
And I change framerate to <framerate>
And I do "Online" download to system
And the system should be equal

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the framerate to be explicit in your scenario background?

You could write a script that updates the .feature with the background, calls specflow's code generator (the one that runs every time you save the file in Visual Studio), compiles and runs your tests. This basically locks in the framerate at compile time.

Or

You could instead change your feature background

```
Background:
Given I have loaded the system configuration
And I change the framerate 
And I do "Online" download to system
And the system should be equal
```

So that the framerate is pulled in at run time

```
 [Given("I change the framerate")]
 public void GivenIChangeTheFramerate()
 {
   framerate = Environment.GetVariable("FRAMERATE");
   // or 
   framerate = File.ReadAllText("Framerate.txt");
   // etc
 }
```

This way its much easier to change the framerate between tests.

Comment: Hi AISki, Thanks for your response. I looking something like first option you have specified. can you give more insight of this please.

Comment: The difference between the two approaches is huge. While the second might take 15 mins, the first will something approaching days of effort. While I've looked at the first approach before I've never actually done it. Mainly because the 2nd approach is so easy. :-)